# Magento upgrade from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.3.3

Tags: upgrade, security, patches, ce-1.9.1.0, magento-1.9.3.3

Our Magento staging environment has been upgraded from 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.3.3 to meet all security purpose through Magento connect.

Once the upgrade process is done through Magento connect, it seems product category and view page elements are missing.

Please advise me to upgrade Magento without theme conflict.

Comment: Did checked your var/log folder for any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are facing it due to cache so try to clear it. If still not resolved, then try to upgrade manually.

Comment: Thanks, buddy ! Manual upgrade working fine. But Mage report shows that SUPEE-8788 need to be updated on Magento1.9.3.3. Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

clear all cache /var/cache and /var/session.
Rename /error/local.xml.sample to /var/local.xml